# PHP parsing xml file with multiple childrens: i only get the first one

Tags: php, xml, parsexml

I'm parsing an XML-file with "file_get_contents" with a foreach loop.
In the XML-file are several childrens () i would like to list all like that:

```
<a href="https://rssdomain.com/the-impact-of-brexit">The impact of Brexit</a>
<a href="https://rssdomain.com/new-rules-recording">New Rules on Recording</a>
```

The XML-file i get:

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>RSS FEED</title>
<link>https://rssdomain.com</link>
<description>
The description of this rss-feed
</description>
<language>en-us</language>
<pubDate>Thu, 07 Mar 2019 12:51:21 GMT</pubDate>
<dc:date>2019-03-07T12:51:21Z</dc:date>
<dc:language>en-us</dc:language>

<item>
    <title>The impact of Brexit</title>
    <link>https://blog.rssdomain.com/the-impact-of-brexit</link>
    <description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</description>
    <category>Author Max Muster</category>
    <category>Author Another Name</category>
    <pubDate>Thu, 07 Mar 2019 12:51:22 GMT</pubDate>
    <author>email@domain.com (Max Muster)</author>
    <guid>https://blog.rssdomain.com/the-impact-of-brexit</guid>
    <dc:date>2019-03-07T12:51:22Z</dc:date>
</item>
<item>
    <title>New Rules on Recording</title>
    <link>https://blog.rssdomain.com/new-rules-recording</link>
    <description>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</description>
    <category>Author Max Muster</category>
    <category>Author Another Name</category>
    <pubDate>Tue, 26 Jan 2015 18:27:00 GMT</pubDate>
    <author>email@domain.com (Max Muster)</author>
    <guid>https://blog.rssdomain.com/new-rules-recording</guid>
    <dc:date>2015-01-26T18:27:00Z</dc:date>
</item>

</channel>
</rss>
```

and this is my PHP code:

```
$source = 'https://rssdomain.com/feed.xml';
    $xmlstr = file_get_contents($source);
    $blogposts = new SimpleXMLElement($source,null,true);

    foreach($blogposts as $item) {
      echo '<h2><a href="'.$item->item->link.'">'.$item->item->title.'</a></h2>';
      // output:  <a href="https://rssdomain.com/the-impact-of-brexit">The impact of Brexit</a>
    }
```

...i don't know why this foreach-loop only returns the first item content, and not all items with contents. what i'm doing wrong?!

Comment: You are not looping over the items, you are looping over the `channel` element. You are accessing `->item` from there, which makes it select the first `item` child of `channel`, so that you still get the data of the first item shown in your loop - but that doesn’t change anything about what that loop iterates over to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

found solution for myself:

```
foreach($blogposts->channel as $channel) {
    foreach($channel->item as $item) {
        echo '<h2><a href="'.$item->link.'">'.$item->title.'</a></h2>';
    }
}
```